# Hide PayPal button using checkout.js

Tags: css, paypal

I'm using [PayPal's checkout.js](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/customize-button/#button-styles) and in the view I'm showing both PayPal button and small buttons of credit cards. But in case I want to show only credit card buttons and hide PayPal button, how can I achieve this?

html:

```
  <div id="paypal-button" class="m-t-20"></div>
```

js:

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: '@Model.Env',
    locale: '@Model.CurrentCulture',
    style: {
        size: 'medium',
        height: 48,
        color: 'silver',
        shape: 'rect',
        label: 'checkout',
        tagline: 'true',
        fundingicons: 'true',
        layout: 'horizontal'
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the funding source, the button will not show.See the Paypal [page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/customize-sdk/#disable-funding).

I expect the code you want looks like this:

```
<script src="https://paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&disable-funding=credit">
</script>
```